# jQuery document.ready will not fire but window.load will

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

I have jQuery loaded in the head section of my page. I am trying to run a short script just before the closing body tag.

`$(window).load` = the code inside this fires.

`jQuery(document).ready` = This code does not fire. I have tried just a simple alert box, and still nothing fires.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Chances are it is something simple or a typo, but I need a second pair of eyes to look at it because  I am just not finding it. Thanks.

page with jQuery: http://sevenclanscasino.designangler.com/warroad/warroad-home

jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    alert('This code fired!');
    // This function pops up a search box when the "Search" menu item is clicked on.
    $('li.search').click(function(event){
        if (event.target.tagName == "A"){
            $('#search-box-container').toggle("fast");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Dude, if is not too much to ask, can't you post the target code instead of your entire web site. We don't want to search for it in your source code.

Comment: It's not firing because of all the errors. Open the console (F12) and all the red stuff are errors.

Comment: Unfortunaly you didnt add the jquery.min to your site, so your jquery plugin is breaking and avoiding your document to be ready

Comment: I removed scripts referencing a third party jQuery plugin, it seemed to do the trick. Not sure why.